# A more optimized solution to pandas apply row-wise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I have this code that does some analysis on a DataFrame. `both_profitable` is `True` if and only if both `long_profitable` and `short_profitable` in that row are `True`. However, the DataFrame is quite large and using pandas `apply` on `axis=1` is more taxing than I'd like.

```py
output["long_profitable"] = (
    df[[c for c in df.columns if "long_profit" in c]].ge(target).any(axis=1)
)
output["short_profitable"] = (
    df[[c for c in df.columns if "short_profit" in c]].ge(target).any(axis=1)
)
output["both_profitable"] = output.apply(
    lambda x: True if x["long_profitable"] and x["short_profitable"] else False,
    axis=1,
)
```

Is there a simpler/more optimized way to achieve this same goal?

Comment: `lambda x: True if x["long_profitable"] == x["short_profitable"] else False` is **not the same** as your definition "True iff both columns are True".

Comment: @PierreD thanks for the heads up, oversight on my part. editing to fix now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `eq` method on the columns:

```
output["both_profitable"] = output["long_profitable"].eq(output["short_profitable"])
```

Or since both columns are boolean, you could use the bitwise `&` operator:

```
output["both_profitable"]  = output["long_profitable"] & output["short_profitable"]
```

Also FYI, you could use `str.contains` + `loc`, instead of a list comprehension to select columns of `df`:

```
output["long_profitable"] = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('long_profit')].ge(target).any(axis=1)
output["short_profitable"] = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('short_profit')].ge(target).any(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

> `both_profitable` is `True` if and only if both `long_profitable` and `short_profitable` in that row are `True`

In other words, `both_profitable` is the result of boolean AND on the two columns.

This can be achieved in several ways:

```py
output['long_profitable'] & output['short_profitable']
```

```py
# for any number of boolean columns, all of which we want to AND
cols = ['long_profitable', 'short_profitable']
output[cols].all(axis=1)
```

```py
# same logic, using prod() -- this is just for fun; use all() instead
output[cols].prod(axis=1).astype(bool)
```

Of course, you can assign any of the above to a new column:

```py
output_modified = output.assign(both_profitable=...)
```

Note: the 2nd and 3rd forms are of particular interest if you are AND-ing many columns.

### Timing

```py
n = 10_000_000
np.random.seed(0)
output = pd.DataFrame({
    'long_profitable': np.random.randint(0, 2, n, dtype=bool),
    'short_profitable': np.random.randint(0, 2, n, dtype=bool),
})

%timeit output['long_profitable'] & output['short_profitable']
# 4.52 ms ± 41.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit output[cols].all(axis=1)
# 18.6 ms ± 53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit output[cols].prod(axis=1).astype(bool)
# 71.6 ms ± 375 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```